# How to accept or deny changes that were made by user on eloquent model?

Tags: laravel

Example:

```
class Game extends Model
{
 //
}
```

1. user "A" has created a Game ( title, desc, etc).
2. user "A" decided to delete a Game  or edit the Game's title.
3. then user "A" will wait for a an approval from admin for these
   changes.

Admin can approve or disapprove these changes:

- If admin approve , apply the new changes that were made.
- If admin dis-approve , don't apply new changes. ( keep old Game's
  data ).

How to accomplish something like this?

**Update:**

I don't think my question was clear. Lets say the user has edited the Game's title ( game's title has been changed in database ) and then Admin dis-approved this change how to restore the previous Game's title?

Comment: You can use flag so admin gets the notification,
or you can have a table where the action and changes are stored and then admin can take the call accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You can add Statuses in your table.

```
$table->enum('create_status', ['Pending', 'Approved'])->default('Pending');
```

In that case, when `User A` created a game, the `create_status` is `"Pending"`

And you can pull all the row that it's `create_status` is `"Pending"` on the Admin side so admin can `approved` it.

Also if `User A` decided to `delete` or `update`

Add column e.g. for delete `delete_status`

```
$table->enum('delete_status', ['Pending', 'Approved'])->default('Pending');
```

Same case as `create_status`

This is just an idea, if you have better than this, go for it.

Comment: I don't think my question was clear. Lets say the user has edited the Game's title 
 ( game's title has been changed in database ) and then Admin dis-approved this change how to restore the previous Game's title?

Comment: I have encounter this before. The solution I made was to create a new table for the changes lets name it pending_changes_table. The row that was edited by `User A` will store there for the mean time. If the admin, approved the changes made by the `User A` then it will overwrite the data on the main_table. Otherwise, delete the changes added on the pending_changes_table

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't have references for that. It is just a simple solution I made just to solve my problem.